# Using Delimeters

Tags: java, html, csv

The following code reads a csv file and defines fields taken from a row of the csv file. The problem is that the firstname column of the csv files has names containing commas "," (for example Charles, Junior). The comma and the name following it is part of the first name. I am having trouble coming up with an efficient way to check for these commas and disregard them as delimeters as they are part of the firstname itself. The existence of the comma creates a new tab which is not desirable. I need to do this without tampering with the csv file. Any suggestions?

```
        //skip the first line since it is column names
        strLine = br.readLine();
        int tokenNumber= 0;

      //read comma separated file line by line
        while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //break comma separated line using ","
            st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                switch (tokenNumber)
                {
                    case 1: firstName = st.nextToken(); break;
                    case 2: lastName = st.nextToken(); break;
                    default: st.nextToken(); break;
                }

                tokenNumber++;
            }
```

Comment: In a valid CSV file, values containing commas are escaped with \. Does your file have that?

Comment: I doubt comma can be both a delimiter and part of text unless its escaped or something

Comment: This isn't javascript code. Did you mean java instead? (java is to javascript, as car is to carpet)

Comment: Yes, pardon the error. And my file does not have \.

Comment: Do you know how many columns are in the file? Your code suggests that it's more than 2.

Comment: Without the , being escaped with \, how would you know (by manually looking at the data file) whether the comma is part of the first name field or not?

Comment: The list of names are given to me. I am not allowed to modify the name as it is standard. But my code has to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with an invalid CSV file like this, your options are fairly limited.

1. If you know how many columns are in the file, and none of the other columns have potential comma problems like this, you could count the total columns in the line, and repeatedly combine the first 2 columns together until you're down to the number of columns you expect
2. If the third column has a predictable value (a number, for example), and assuming the second column will never have comma problems, you can repeatedly combine the first two columns until the third column contains a value matching the pattern you expect
3. If you've got a list of allowed values for the first and/or last name columns, you can repeatedly combine the first two columns until the values in both the first and second columns have valid values.

The key question to ask yourself is "how would you handle this process manually?". If the manual process depends on using some human reasoning such as recognizing common names, then you're going to have a hard time doing it in code.